# Domain Restrictions SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a domain restriction but I don't know which one is better and why, which are the difference between them?

For example I tried to create a domain like this:

```
ALTER TABLE PACIENT ADD CONSTRAINT pacient_sex_c0 
CHECK (SexCD='M' or SexCD='F')
```

Or is better to create like:

```
CREATE DOMAIN pacient_sex
CONSTRAINT sex
CHECK (SexCD='M' or SexCD='F')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE DOMAIN` is not a valid DDL statement in Oracle.  So if your goal is to have the database enforce your restriction, you would need a constraint.

SQL Developer Data Modeler has the concept of a domain when you are defining a data model.  I'm not aware of any way to create such a domain via SQL rather than via the GUI, though.  If you define a domain in SQL Developer Data Modeler when you are creating the data model, when SQL Developer generates the DDL, it should create a constraint for you if your domain restricts the set of valid values.